# How to show a different page after X amount of page views?

Tags: php

I currently have the following code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['views'])) { 
$_SESSION['views'] = 0;
}

$_SESSION['views'] = $_SESSION['views']+1;

if ($_SESSION['views'] > 100) {
Execute Code
}

?>
```

I'm trying so that after 100 page views the content of the page changes.

THe problem with this code is that it doesnt work to every users the same way. It counts individually instead of globally to all visitors.

Is there a way that I could achieve this?

Comment: you'll have to store it in a database, or file

Comment: Using session is not the way if you want to set something globally. Sessions are unique for each user. You can instead store view somewhere else. Like a file, database etc/.

Comment: Database seems overkill if you don't already have one in your app, and even if you do have one...

Answer (score 0):

A `$_SESSION` is stored for every user (not for a whole application), so you should use a database or text file to store the counter.

Comment: So should I do a session that +1 a txt?

Comment: Remember you don't need `$_SESSION` at all with file functions. See this tutorial: http://php.about.com/od/finishedphp1/ss/flat_file_count.htm

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION` allows you to store information per-user, not globally.

The easiest way would be to store the number of views in a file, with a code like this :

```
// read previous count
$filename = 'hitcount.txt';
$handle = fopen($filename, 'r');
$views = trim(fgets($handle)) + 1; // read and increment for current view.
fclose($handle);

$handle = fopen($filename, 'w');
fwrite($handle, $views); // replace previous count
fclose($handle);

if($views > 100){
// do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$counter = file_get_contents("counter.txt");
$counter++;
file_put_contents("counter.txt", $counter);

if ($counter > 100){
    print("yey");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by Pieter, Rene

Sessions are user base as its a larger version of a cookie in essence.
The easiest and fastest way if you don't have too many connections is a simple mysql DB
that connects and then update the visit counter for a given day

```
UPDATE visit SET visit_counter = visit_counter+1 WHERE date = '$today';
```

where $today = date("Y-m-d");

just an example (where visit is the table - visit_counter is the visit_counter column)